# Table manipulation in power bi with R

Tags: r, powerbi

I'm working on a data analysis project in Power BI and I'm trying to perform a variance analysis on a table called CP_Filter. This table was created using the DAX expression:

```
Filtro_CP = GROUPBY(FILTER(Responses, RELATED(Questions[FullName])="CP1_TOT"), Responses[RespondentId], Responses[Value])
```

In this process, you joined the Answers, Questions, Respondents, and Responses tables using relationships. The objective is to identify significant differences by dates in the CP_Filter table. However, when you run the script.I only get the data and I cannot apply any analysis

[image]

I opened the data in R and I only get this.

I expected to obtain significant and complete results from the analysis of variance that would allow me to identify significant differences by dates in the CP_Filter table.

The data I get is limited. Is it possible to perform variance analysis in Power BI this way, or should I consider a change to the data structure? Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?"